# Is there a nice way to link to a named anchor in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a table of contents on one 'page' of a React.js Single Page Application (SPA). Each of the items in the table of contents is a link to a section on another page.

e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='/newpage#atarget'>A Target</a></li>
    <li><a href='/newpage#btarget'>B Target</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

which will link to a new page containing something like

```
<a name='atarget' />
<h2>A Target</h2>
    ...

<a name='btarget' />
<h2>bTarget</h2>
    ...
```

What I am finding is that, even manually browsing to /newpage/atarget, I do not end up at the correct spot. I assume that is because React.js renders the page after load.

What I would like is

1. react-router to be able to use the links on the Table of Contents to avoid a refetch
2. Have the named targets work, either from a link, or when manually typing into the URL bar

My current solution is to look at the hash location on each page load and scroll to that position for item 2. This seems clunky, and I hope you out there have a better way. I do not have a solution for item 1.